# VS 2010 Shortcut for debugging a specific project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with a dozen projects.
I use <kbd>Ctrl+F9</kbd> to launch a specific project, however I have to select manually the desired project each time.
 I would be happy if I could assign a specific shortcut to debug each project.
I use AutoHotKey for global shortcuts to launch project applications outside of VS but for debugging I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: I doubt it's currently possible, but I agree that it would be a nice feature to have. Maybe look at adding it to http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/

Comment: @adelphus Yup. I'd rather spend a night or two coding this kind of feature myself and offer it as public VS plugin than wait for MS'Devs to offer it in "VS 2050" (^^)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly, click the DEBUG menu bar item, and then a submenu item?
-- Or perhaps there is a command line option, to open a project in Visual Studio, via the `Run` command?
-- (Regarding: 'than wait for ... Devs', I am SO sympathetic).